# How to modify a timepicker where time range can not be overlapped

Tags: javascript, jquery, timepicker

In my app i am using a 24 hours timepicker ,that is used for scheduling interview.Now my requirement is that i can add multiple interview schedule ,and each time the next interview schedule will be after the previous interview schedule,i.e i am adding

```
A.B.Sen     4:45:00     7:23:45
H Basu      5:17:00     8:25:12
```

This is wrong ,timing can not be overlapped ,the interview schedule of  H Basu will always  start  after 7:23:45 and so on ,is this possible??

```
     $(".time").timepicker({

        'timeFormat': 'H:i:s' 
    });
```

Here is the fiddle link 
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/08uq09cL/1/)

I am using this api ,please tell me if this is possible ?Thanks in advance

Comment: can you provide fiddle so it will be easier to anwser your question

Comment: @Mahadevan please check i have provide a link

Comment: any body please help